# dummy variables in pandas based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a dummy variable in pandas which has the value of 1 if the value in column A is greater than 0, and 0 if otherwise. This dummy should be stored in a new column, G.

```
               A         B         C         D         E         F  
2016-01-01  0.571650  0.427669  0.090381 -0.765132 -1.164994  0.244477   
2016-01-02  0.834616  0.938302 -0.428445 -0.067147  0.126845  0.783122   
2016-01-03  1.996946 -0.178791  1.478010  0.424868  2.311478 -0.357036   
2016-01-04  0.423200  0.229080  1.414170  0.258490  0.931763  0.096947   
2016-01-05 -0.400117 -0.785149  1.748607  1.777462 -0.509319  0.314151
```

Currently, I have this

```
a = []
for row in df['A']:
    if row > 0:
        a.append(1)
    else:
        a.append(0)
df['G'] = a
```

This works, but I have the gut feeling there must be a better, simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compare the entire column and cast the `dtype` using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype):

```
In [21]:
df['G'] = (df['A'] > 0).astype(int)
df

Out[21]:
                   A         B         C         D         E         F  G
2016-01-01  0.571650  0.427669  0.090381 -0.765132 -1.164994  0.244477  1
2016-01-02  0.834616  0.938302 -0.428445 -0.067147  0.126845  0.783122  1
2016-01-03  1.996946 -0.178791  1.478010  0.424868  2.311478 -0.357036  1
2016-01-04  0.423200  0.229080  1.414170  0.258490  0.931763  0.096947  1
2016-01-05 -0.400117 -0.785149  1.748607  1.777462 -0.509319  0.314151  0
```

The comparison generates a boolean `Series` with `dtype` `bool`:

```
In [22]:
df['A'] > 0

Out[22]:
2016-01-01     True
2016-01-02     True
2016-01-03     True
2016-01-04     True
2016-01-05    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

So casting the type to `int` converts `True` to `1` and `False` to `0`

For a 50k df:

```
In [36]:
%%timeit 
a=[]
for row in df['A']:
    if row > 0:
        a.append(1)
    else:
        a.append(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.1 ms per loop

In [37]:
%timeit df['G'] = (df['A'] > 0).astype(int)

1000 loops, best of 3: 423 µs per loop
```

So the vectorised version is ~35X faster and will scale better with larger dfs